# select .xlsx files through a pop up window and to copy data from them and paste them after last used row on a loop

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

The below code return allows me to match header with my dashboard file and apac file and copy data into dashboard file and "temp calc" sheet.the problem is that apac is not the only file, i need to be able to select files through a pop up window and run this code on a loop so that it will paste data from each file after the last used row in "temp calc" after matching headers. I'am unable to do both, please advise ?

Thanks,

Mathew

```
Sub copyCol()


     Sheets("Temp Calc").Select

    'Clear existing sheet data except headers
        Rows(1).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rows.Count - 1).ClearContents



        Dim lastCol, lastRow As Long, k As Long, a As Variant, b As Variant, cmpRng As Range
        Dim mastCol As Long, mastRng As Range, n As Long
        Dim Wbk As Workbook

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Worksheets("Temp Calc").Select

           lastCol = Worksheets("Temp Calc").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
           lastRow = Worksheets("Temp Calc").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlDown).Row

        Set cmpRng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, lastCol))
        a = cmpRng
        Set Wbk = Workbooks.Open("G:\work\APAC.xlsx")
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
        mastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        Set mastRng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, mastCol))
        b = mastRng

        For k = 1 To lastCol
            For n = 1 To mastCol
                If UCase(a(1, k)) = UCase(b(1, n)) Then
                Windows("APAC-Personal Assignment.xlsx").Activate
                    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, n), Cells(lastRow, n)).Copy
                    Windows("Dashboard_for_Roshan.xlsm").Activate
                    Worksheets("Temp Calc").Select
                    Cells(2, k).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
                    False, Transpose:=False

                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        Next

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

        Exit Sub

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to implement proposed code (below) which goal is to: **A)** show open file dialog with multiselect option, **B)** after you press ok it will open (**C)** and close) all selected files.

I think you will be able to join the solution with your code. Before you do itsimply try the code to understand how it is working.

```
Sub Solution_for_multifiles()

    Dim SelectedFiles As Object
    Set SelectedFiles = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        SelectedFiles.Show

    If SelectedFiles.SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
        'here is the code which will run for all files selected
        Dim fileOne
        Dim Wbk As Workbook
        For Each fileOne In SelectedFiles.SelectedItems
            Set Wbk = Workbooks.Open(fileOne)
            'your code here...
            '.........

            'remeber to close before move to next file
            Wbk.Close
        Next

    Else
        MsgBox "No file was selected...", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error!"
        Err.Clear
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: that was very helpful KazjJaw, i hope i can build further on that. :)
Could you also help me to integrate my code with your code with comments so i can understand it better. I've gone though a lot of similar examples but i can't grasp the process.
thanks mate,
Mathew

Comment: in this situation the integration is very individual problem which, without tests, is hard to support. But I think you will cope after some suggestions: add my code after this line `a = cmpRng` and move your code starting from `Set Wbk...` to second `next` inside my loop where I stated `'your code here`. Next run it with F8 key to check if it works...

Comment: i did the above and i get an error on this line 
Windows("APAC-Personal Assignment.xlsx").Activate

a reference issue, what do i change it to?

Comment: with the line i get error number 9 " out of range"
without it i get error number 1004 " application defined or object defined error"

Comment: as I said, it's very difficult to help you without file structure you have... as I said I think there isn't `APAC-Personal assignment.xlsx` file open...

Comment: as much as i can understand does this line have to be replaced with the reference to the open workbook ?
yes i checked the apac book does not open at the time.

Comment: you should understand that StackOverflow is site to give support but not to solve all problems. So, try on your own step by step. I think there is simple logic and you can figure it out. Optionally you could ask separate question(s) relating to specific part of your code.